# How can I verify the result of a reCAPTCHA in PHP

Tags: php, comments, captcha

I am currently working on a website, and I've had some problems with spammers on my comment system. So, I am implementing a reCAPTCHA (maybe some scanners later). I have registered my site with Google, and now I have embedded the code. But, I need to get the result (not checked, succeeded, failed) of my reCAPTCHA in PHP, since I use that language for the comment system. How can I do this?

Comment: If you're using Google recaptcha then they have code examples you can use

Comment: There is this amazing new thing called Google and if you type a phrase like "php recaptcha code example" it tells you where to find it. :P

Comment: Lol im not stupid i have been researching.

Comment: I don't understand `But, I need to get the result (not checked, succeeded, failed)` :D pls tell me if you haven't succeeded with your prob.

Answer (score 2):

Sign up for a api key it's free. And use the following code example.

https://github.com/google/recaptcha/tree/master/examples

Answer (score 0):

If you are sending captcha request by post method using Curl PHP. You can use the following code by get the respose:

```
  $privatekey = "paste_your_privatekey";
  $responseKey = $_POST["g-recaptcha-response"];
  $userIP = $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];



  /////Curl Start///////
  $ch = curl_init();

  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify");
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,
              "secret=$privatekey&response=$responseKey&remoteip=$userIP");

  // Receive server response ...
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

  $server_output = curl_exec($ch);
  $response = json_decode($server_output);

  //view response
  var_dump($response);
  curl_close ($ch);
  /////Curl Close///////

  // Further processing ...
  if ($response->success == "true") {
    Success……..
  }esle{
    Failed…………….
  }
```